# Bluetooth inquiry - possibility to receive inquiry responses on more than one sensor

Tags: bluetooth

Question for the Bluetooth specialists here. I've been doing research on movements of pedestrians, cyclists and cars with Bluetooth tracking. Up until now I have derived trajectories out of these data in a pure proximity way: so a device is assumed to be at the exact location of a sensor as long as it is being detected (using some kind of buffer time in between detections). All of this is purely based on inquiries, and not on actual connections. I register rssi values but don't use them yet.

One stumbling block we have identified is the interference caused by inquiring devices when they are placed in each others detection range, leading to inaccurate/sparse rssi values. Then I came up with a possibly far-fetched idea, which may or may not be implementable :)

Would it be possible to let one Bluetooth sensor enter the inquiry substate & transmit inquiry packets, but let one or more other sensors receive the inquiry replies to that inquiry packet. So we would have this situation:

sensor A: enters inquiry substate, sends inquiry packet P

sensors B & C: enter inquiry substate, don't send any inquiry packets, but only listen for inquiry responses to inquiry packet P from sensor A.

I suppose to do this, sensors A, B and C would at least have to synchronize their inquiry hopping sequence. But there may be more necessities.

Is this at all possible ? Has this been done before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard bluetooth only the inquiring device listens for the inquiry responses to its inquiry. (The reasoning is the same as what you have mentioned - due to the need for inquiry hopping sequence to be synchronized both in timing as well as frequencies of the inquiry hop sequence) 
So it is not possible for B & C to listen for responses triggered by A's inquiry, using standard bluetooth hardware.

For your application the latest Bluetooth 4.0 (Bluetooth Low Energy) seems like a perfect fit. Which has the concept of advertising , so a sensor can be configured to behave as an advertiser and other sensors can be configured to in scanning state (listening to advertising)

Comment: Interesting, but I suppose both the sensor and the mobile devices that we need to discover would need to support the Bluetooth 4.0 protocol for this ? This would take quite a while, since the first 4.0 modules are only now released into the public. Would it also be possible to discover devices without any need for cooperation from the owner of the mobile device (as it happens now) ?

Comment: Bluetooth 4.0 is already in many devices - latest iPhone 4S, Mac Mini/Air , Droid Razar etc, also a number of sensor devices , so I think it is a great time to switch over to 4.0 for sensor type applications, Not sure what you mean by "cooperation from the owner" - There are/will be APIs which allow you to programmatically discover and identify devices without need for user intervention

Comment: Suppose you would like to somehow implement this behavior. On what level would you have to implement this protocol adaptation ? BlueZ, HCI, or even deeper ? Is this doable for non-experts with general programming skills ?

Comment: It is possible to do this at the application level, i.e by non experts with general programing skills (pls - accept the answer it it was useful)